# ubuntu cmake link boost staticly

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have an c++ code and it depends on boost `filesystem`

I just installed it like this

> sudo apt-get install libboost-dev

and with cmake I used:

```
find_package( Boost  1.5.9 REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)  
MESSAGE("Boost information:") 
MESSAGE("  Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}") 
MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}") 
MESSAGE("  Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
target_link_libraries(project  ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

And I ran make and its compile without error but its compile it as shared library
I just search for make it static so what I did first I uninstall the libboost-dev with

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove libboost-dev
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove libboost-dev
```

and I downloaded the boost source from 
[here](http://www.boost.org/users/download/)

I downloaded the `boost_1_66_0.tar.gz`

I extracted it in `home/build` and ran this command:

```
./boostrap.sh
./b2 --target=static
 sudo ./b2 install
```

All of the above was done without error

but I failed to link that to cmake for compile static library I tried this in cmake:

```
 set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR home/build/boost)
 set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR home/build/boost/stage/lib)
 find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
 include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
 link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

 add_executable(project main.cpp)
 target_link_libraries( main ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

But seems I failed to link and it shows this error:

```
fatal error: file system.hpp: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This is a compilation error. Absolute paths typically should start with `/` : `set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/build/boost)`

Comment: @VTT i will try 5 second

Comment: @VTT same problem

Comment: No need to build boost by yourself. Use the libboost-dev package and add the following variable before the find_package call `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)`. And its a good idea to use the multithreaded version of boost libs by also setting `set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)`. BTW what version of CMake are you using?

Comment: @vre i used that in cmake and its still use shared library so i think i must build it as static my cmake version its last 3.5.2

Comment: another thing those message  `MESSAGE("Boost information:") MESSAGE(" Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}") MESSAGE(" Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}") MESSAGE(" Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")`

output

`Boost information:
  Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: /home/medo/build/boost
  Boost_LIBRARIES: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so
  Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Comment: Path to include directory (which contains header files) normally ended with `include`, so `/home/medo/build/boost` looks suspicious. Also, header name `file system.hpp` is definitely wrong: it should be `filesystem.h` or even `boost/filesystem.h`. Instead of `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` variable, hint for [find_package(Boost)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/module/FindBoost.html) should be `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` variable. After changing hints in `CMakeLists.txt`, it is better to clear the cache of the last build (remove `CMakeCache.txt` from the build directory).

Comment: @Tsyvarev the file is named `boost/filesystem.hpp`. @smsm smsm You wont get it to work with your cmake version and Boost 1.66. Boost changed its library naming scheme with version 1.66 and CMake handle this starting with version 3.11 (which was just released a couple of days ago). And filesystem is not a header only Boost lib, so this wont work.

Comment: @smsm smsm your error message show a space in `file system.hpp` is that a typo? The include file is named `boost/filesystem.hpp`.

Comment: @vre sorry for that i just wrote that error without copied its filesystem.hpp

Comment: Can you restart your trial and install `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` and try the `set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)` and `set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)` before `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)`? libboost-all-dev is the complete development package and should provide everything you need. You can omit the Boost Version in the find_package call, it picks the one installed.

Comment: @vre i will try it again but iam sure its will link it shared

Comment: And always clear the CMakeCache.txt file, I forgot to mention.